# Visual Studio 2012 Build Progress Bar

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've just rebuilt my computer and am having trouble finding the build progress bar that I had previously installed for Visual Studio 2012.

This bar was simply a full-windows-width progress bar that was pinned just above the Output/Error windows. The bar would appear while solutions were building. It would stay green while the build had no errors and turn red when an error was hit.

Any ideas how to get this functionality back?

Comment: I think CodeMaid had that.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right! I'll give that a try a bit later today.

Comment: @GaTechThomas Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, CodeMaid was it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per answer from comments, the build progress bar described came from CodeMaid:

[image]